# Finding the nth largest in an int array

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to find the nth largest numbers in an `int` `array`, I already have a `linq` statement that returns something but it's not passing the used cases that are set up. The `array` is:

```
var numbers = new[] { 5, 7, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9 };
```

My code is:

```
  var result = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
                .SkipWhile(group =>
                {
                    n -= group.Count();
                    return n > 0;
                })
                .First()
                .ToArray();
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting the expected results?

```
  result[0] == 9
  result[1] == 7
```

Comment: And what are you getting?

Comment: result[0] == 7
  result[1] == 7

Comment: For what `n`? Anyway, you're skipping `n` first elements, so for any `n > 0` you will not get `9`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we find the i'th greatest element of the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124257/how-can-we-find-the-ith-greatest-element-of-the-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Take()` to get the `n` largest items after the collection is ordered descending :

```
var result = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
                    .Take(n)
                    .Select(group => group.Key)
                    .ToArray();
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/etB4JX)</kbd>**

or use `Skip(n-1).Take(1)` if you mean to get only the *nth* item instead.