# QuickSelect Algorithm Understanding

Tags: algorithm, quickselect

I've been poring over various tutorials and articles that discuss quicksort and quickselect, however, my understanding of them is still shaky.

Given this code structure, I need to be able to grasp and explain how quickselect works.

```
// return the kth smallest item
int quickSelect(int items[], int first, int last, int k) {
    int pivot = partition(items, first, last);
    if (k < pivot-first) {
        return quickSelect(items, first, pivot, k);
    } else if (k > pivot) {
        return quickSelect(items, pivot+1, last, k-pivot);
    } else {
        return items[k];
    }
}
```

I need a little help with breaking down into pseudo-code, and while I haven't been provided with the partition function code, I'd like to understand what it would do given the quickselect function provided.

I know how quicksort works, just not quickselect. The code I just provided is an example we were given on how to format quick select.

EDIT: The corrected code is

```
int quickSelect(int items[], int first, int last, int k) 
{
    int pivot = partition(items, first, last);
    if (k < pivot-first+1) 
    { //boundary was wrong
        return quickSelect(items, first, pivot, k);
    } 
    else if (k > pivot-first+1) 
    {//boundary was wrong
        return quickSelect(items, pivot+1, last, k-pivot);
    }
    else 
    {
        return items[pivot];//index was wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be too specific with my needs - A general understanding of quickselect is what would help most, the code I provided is an example of it.

Comment: That information from MIT is on sorting, not selecting. As far as I can see.

Comment: Why do we need these : pivot-first+1 and k-pivot

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The important part in quick select is partition. So let me explain that first.

Partition in quick select picks a `pivot` (either randomly or first/last element). Then it rearranges the list in a way that all elements less than `pivot` are on left side of pivot and others on right. It then returns index of the `pivot` element.

Now here we are finding kth smallest element. After partition cases are:

1. `k == pivot`. Then you have already found kth smallest. This is because the way partition is working. There are exactly `k - 1` elements that are smaller than the `kth` element.
2. `k < pivot`. Then kth smallest is on the left side of `pivot`.
3. `k > pivot`. Then kth smallest is on the right side of pivot. And to find it you actually have to find `k-pivot` smallest number on right.

Comment: Does the code example I provided conduct those 3 checks against k?

Comment: I notice I don't check k == pivot

Comment: @Andrew, `k == pivot` is captured in the the last `else` block in your code.

Comment: @Andrew, also not that `k < pivot - first` is to do the comparison with reference to the `first` index passed.

Answer (score 5):

btw, your code has a few bugs..

```
int quickSelect(int items[], int first, int last, int k) {
    int pivot = partition(items, first, last);
    if (k < pivot-first+1) { //boundary was wrong
        return quickSelect(items, first, pivot, k);
    } else if (k > pivot-first+1) {//boundary was wrong
        return quickSelect(items, pivot+1, last, k-pivot);
    } else {
        return items[pivot];//index was wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: yours has a bug too. second quickSelect should be `quickSelect(items, pivot+1, last, k- (pivot-first+1));`

Answer (score 3):

Partition is pretty simple: it rearranges the elements so those less than a selected pivot are at lower indices in the array than the pivot and those larger than the pivot are at higher indices in the array.

I talked about the rest it in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074394/179910).

Answer (score 1):

```
int quickSelect(int A[], int l, int h,int k)
{
        int p = partition(A, l, h); 
        if(p==(k-1)) return A[p];
        else if(p>(k-1)) return quickSelect(A, l, p - 1,k);  
        else return quickSelect(A, p + 1, h,k);

}
```

//    partition function same as QuickSort

Answer (score 1):

I was reading CLRS Algorithm book to learn quick select algorithm, we may implement the algorithm in easy way.

```
package selection;    
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class will calculate and print Nth ascending order element
 * from an unsorted array in expected time complexity O(N), where N is the
 * number of elements in the array.
 * 
 * The important part of this algorithm the randomizedPartition() method.
 * 
 * @author kmandal
 *
 */
public class QuickSelect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = { 7, 1, 2, 6, 0, 1, 96, -1, -100, 10000 };
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("The " + i + "th ascending order element is "
                    + quickSelect(A, 0, A.length - 1, i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Similar to Quick sort algorithm partitioning approach works, but after
     * that instead of recursively work on both halves here will be recursing
     * into desired half. This step ensure to the expected running time to be
     * O(N).
     * 
     * @param A
     * @param p
     * @param r
     * @param i
     * @return
     */
    private static int quickSelect(int[] A, int p, int r, int i) {
        if (p == r) {
            return A[p];
        }
        int partitionIndex = randomizedPartition(A, p, r);
        if (i == partitionIndex) {
            return A[i];
        } else if (i < partitionIndex) {// element is present in left side of
                                        // partition
            return quickSelect(A, p, partitionIndex - 1, i);
        } else {
            return quickSelect(A, partitionIndex + 1, r, i);// element is
                                                            // present in right
            // side of partition
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Similar to Quick sort algorithm this method is randomly select pivot
     * element index. Then it swap the random pivot element index with right
     * most element. This random selection step is expecting to make the
     * partitioning balanced. Then in-place rearranging the array to make all
     * elements in the left side of the pivot element are less than pivot
     * element and the right side elements are equals or grater than the pivot
     * element. Finally return partition index.
     * 
     * @param A
     * @param p
     * @param r
     * @return
     */
    private static int randomizedPartition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
        int partitionIndex = p;
        int random = p + new Random().nextInt(r - p + 1);// select
                                                            // pseudo random
                                                            // element
        swap(A, random, r);// swap with right most element
        int pivot = A[r];// select the pivot element
        for (int i = p; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
            if (A[i] < pivot) {
                swap(A, i, partitionIndex);
                partitionIndex++;
            }
        }
        swap(A, partitionIndex, r);
        return partitionIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Swapping 2 elements in an array.
     * 
     * @param A
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    private static void swap(int[] A, int i, int j) {
        if (i != j && A[i] != A[j]) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}


Output:
The 0th ascending order element is -100
The 1th ascending order element is -1
The 2th ascending order element is 0
The 3th ascending order element is 1
The 4th ascending order element is 1
The 5th ascending order element is 2
The 6th ascending order element is 6
The 7th ascending order element is 7
The 8th ascending order element is 96
The 9th ascending order element is 10000
```

Comment: I still think you could add some explanations to your code.

Comment: I have added meaningful description.

Answer (score 0):

```
int partition(vector<int> &vec, int left, int right, int pivotIndex)
{
        int pivot = vec[pivotIndex];
        int partitionIndex = left;

        swap(vec[pivotIndex],vec[right]);
        for(int i=left; i < right; i++) {
                if(vec[i]<pivot) {
                        swap(vec[i],vec[partitionIndex]);
                        partitionIndex++;
                }
        }
        swap(vec[partitionIndex], vec[right]);

        return partitionIndex;
}

int select(vector<int> &vec, int left, int right, int k)
{
        int pivotIndex;
        if (right == left) {
                return vec[left];
        }
        pivotIndex = left + rand() % (right-left);

        pivotIndex = partition(vec,left,right,pivotIndex);
        if (pivotIndex == k) {
                return vec[k];
        } else if(k<pivotIndex) {
                /*k is present on the left size of pivotIndex*/
                return partition(vec,left,pivotIndex-1, k);
        } else {
                /*k occurs on the right size of pivotIndex*/
                return partition(vec, pivotIndex+1, right, k);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, when `pivotIndex == k` the value on that index is returned, whilst in other the `partition` is called and the index of the partition is returned. No idea why this has been up voted.